# Em Javascript - Como fazer o input aceitar virgula e ponto nesse meu escript. Retornando os valores das parcelas

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form name="frm" method="post">
        valor: <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" onchange="alteraPonto()">
        <input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="calcularParcelas('valor')">
        <p id="resultado"></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function calcularParcelas(campo) {
    var valor = document.getElementById(campo).value

    var entrada = Math.floor(valor / 3) + valor % 3; // Math.floor traz o resultado inteiro da divisão somado ao resto(% = mod) da divisão
    var parcelas = Math.floor(valor / 3); // O próprio javascript já cria as parcelas na chamada parcelas        
    var solucao = "<hr><p>Valor da Compra:   " + valor + "</p>" +
        " <p>Valor Entrada:   " + entrada + "</p>" +
        " <p>Parcela 01:   " + parcelas + "</p>" +
        " <p>Parcela 02: " + parcelas + "</p>";

    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = solucao;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz o seguinte que deve funcionar:

```
var temp = document.getElementById(campo).value;
var valor = temp.replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo interesse. Funcionou!!! Valeu!!!

Comment: De nada amigo! Estamos aqui para fortalecer a comunidade em Portugués, um abraço!